# XCode See code visual effect in storyboard

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I'm making an iOS app with XCode 6.1, targeted operation system version is iOS 7 and iOS 8. I wanna change the border color of a UITextField, since I'm not sure how to do this using interface builder, I simply added this line in the view controller:

```
self.input_username.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```

It worked as expected when running the app with simulator, now I wonder if it is possible to show the effect in storyboard? Because for what I can tell, even when executing the app, the border color becomes red, it is still black(the default color) in interface builder... I don't want to run the app every time when I made a little change for visual effect by code...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? You want storyboard change as your code settings? I have't seen this before, and I don't think that's possible. Since they are two ways to the same purpose.

Comment: Yes， I want the storyboard to reflect what I've set up in my view controller code, like border color, border width etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just can see the change in storyboard only when you draw custom view, and you can use the **@IBDesignable** in your custom view's declaration, such as `@IBDesignable class CounterView: UIView {}`. Then in your storyboard, you set a view's class name as "CounterView" and change code in the `override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {}` in your custom view's class, you will see the view in storyboard also be changed.